# HTML <div> tag with formatting

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

hi im working on a angular project and im  having a string (actually it is a piece of code)

```
package testData;\r\n\r\npublic class testOverride extends mainClass {\r\n\r\n\tpublic void add(int a) {\r\n\t\tint c = a + b + 2;\r\n\t\tSystem.out.println(c);\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n\
```

i needed to highlight some of the lines in this string because of that im splitting  it from `\n`  and adding it to an array so i can loop it highlight the line i want

on typescript

```
lineList:{};//line array
this.lineList = this.file.split("\n");//splitting and adding to array
```

on html

```
<div *ngFor="let lines of lineList">
      <div>{{lines}}</div>
</div>
```

then the formatting `\r` has been gone

[image]

is there any way to add these line with formatting?

Comment: How do you want to present the `\r`? Actually put it in tye html? Is it should be tab (`\t`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` is not doing what you think it's doing. It's called a "carriage return" and in some OSes (mainly Windows, don't know if there are any others) it's required before a `\n` to cause a line break. What's causing the indentation is in fact the `\t`.

Regular inline or block elements don't preserve whitespace present in the markup. There's a special tag `<pre>` however, that does preserve whitespace. It also sets the font family to a monospace font by default.

In order to imitate a `<pre>` tag if you have to use a `<div>` for whatever reason, you can achieve the same output by using CSS' `white-space: pre;` and `font-family: monospace`.

```css
.code {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<h3>Regular div tag</h3>
<div>
package testData;
public class testOverride extends mainClass {
 public void add(int a) {
  int c = a + b + 2;
  System.out.println(c);
 }
}
</div>

<h3>pre tag</h3>
<pre>
package testData;
public class testOverride extends mainClass {
 public void add(int a) {
  int c = a + b + 2;
  System.out.println(c);
 }
}
</pre>

<h3>div with CSS <code>white-space: pre;</code></h3>
<div class="code">
package testData;
public class testOverride extends mainClass {
 public void add(int a) {
  int c = a + b + 2;
  System.out.println(c);
 }
}
</div>
```